# Woocommerce quantity groups

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a woocommerce wholesale store. Because it's dropshipping, customers will only be able order a set amount of an item. For instance 12-24-36-48-100-130 are the possible quantities. I searched on Google and can't find a plugin or way of restricting the quantity. Ideally there quantity field would be a dropdown containing those quantities. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can change the plus/minus "Step" see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25266074/383847)

Comment: This won't work because some quantity are not standard steps (100-130)

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, you'd want to [override](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) the `global/quantity-input.php` template.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `global/quantity-input.php` and replace it with something:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <?php $steps = array( 12, 24, 36, 48, 100, 130 ); ?>
    <select name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" >
        <option value=""><?php _e( 'Select Quantity', 'your-theme' );?></option>
        <?php foreach( $steps as $step ){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($step);?>" <?php echo checked( $step, $input_value );?>><?php echo $step;?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

That would replace all quantity inputs with your custom dropdown, which may or may not be ideal.

Comment: This with an option for a list of quantities on the product page would be ideal I guess